# Does quantum field theory and field excitations explain the double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, double-slit-experiment

I'm a student and I'd like to confirm my understanding of Quantum field theory (QFT). QFT says particles are actually excited states in pre-existing fields. Each field is only excited with specific energy value or its integer multiples, so it looks like one or more particles but never half a particle. Every excitation (or "particle") has its own field with its own excitation value but these fields may affect each other. For example when an electron seems to emit a photon it doesn't mean a photon particle was hidden inside an electron particle but actually the excitation in electron field caused an excitation in the photon field.
[QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory)

So in the double-slit experiment the fields already fills both slits, When an excitation travels it's always through only one of the slits, since it is never divided into fractional excitations, but it affects the field itself which fills both slits. The interference pattern is because the excitation affected the field path probability for following excitations travelling through this field. I can visualize it as the excitation leaving traces on the field that affects path of following excitations. So probability functions in quantum physics are probabilities of excitations affecting path of following excitations passing through a field. The act of measurement erases this interference because the energy of an observer particle, which is actually just another energy excitation, affects the field and erases these traces thus removing the interference.

This seems to me the most logical interpretation of the double-slit experiment.
Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: It is more like the EM field can carry virtual photons (force carriers ) as well real photons. An excited atom's field is exerting forces (virtual photons) everywhere but then the field may resonant with another unexcited atom at which point a real photon is transmitted.  The slits affect the virtual photons of the EM field which eventually result is a real photon path thus the "interference" pattern. The word "interference" is historical, single photon experiments also show the pattern!  2 photons do not cancel, that would be a violation of conservation of energy.